# Backward compatibility for command names

Tags: macros, package-writing, documentclass-writing

I have made a class file. It defines commands for use in document files.
I want to change some of the command names, but I also want old document
files to work without changing them.

Here's an example to illustrate:

```
\begin{filecontents}{a.cls} 
\ProvidesClass{a}
\LoadClass{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{scrpage2}
%
\def\commandnameA#1{\def\@commandnameA{#1}}
\commandnameA{}
%
\newpagestyle{a}{{}{}{A:\@commandnameA}}{{}{}{}}
\pagestyle{a}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{a}
\begin{document}
\commandnameA{test}
test
\end{document}
```

For this example I want to change "commandnameA" to "commandnameB" in
the class file and have the document file work whether it contains
`\commandnameA{test}` or `\commandnameB{test}`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\let\commandnameB\commandnameA` in your class file.  Then the two macros are the same!

Comment: or `\def\commandnameB{\commandnameA}` if you want to keep both in sync even after `\commandnameA` got redefined.

Answer (score 6):

You may add a warning that `\commandnameA` is deprecated:

```
\def\commandnameB{%
  \commandnameA%
  \ClassWarning{yourclass}{Command \string\commandnameA\space is deprecated.%
  \MessageBreak Use \string\commandnameA\space instead.}%
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `\commandnameA` and/or `\commandnameB` expect an argument, Tobi's solution should have been

```
\protected\def\commandnameB{%
  \ClassWarning{myclass}{Command `\string\commandnameA' is deprecated.
  \MessageBreak Use `\string\commandnameB' instead}%
  \commandnameA
}
```

I have added `\protected` because `\commandnameB` is not expandable.

Comment: It would be nicer if you could keep your answer self-contained and could avoid questions to the poster and others.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Thanks. I have removed *why?*.

Comment: I didn't mean you should remove the question. I had hoped you could expand on it further. It would provide more insight and would improve the answer. That's all.